# Want to be able to save cities that are large into a vector in Clojure

Tags: function, loops, vector, clojure, scope

So i want to take cities from a csv file that passes through my large function(which determines if they have a population of over 500000) and if true the city gets saved into a vector. But when I try to save it with my function all the letters are double spaced from each other?

Here is what I have so far:

```clj
(defn closest-city-pairs []
  (with-open [rdr (reader)]
    (vec
      (for [line (drop 1 (line-seq rdr))
            :let [y (string/split line #",")]
            :when (= true (large(y 0)))]
        (let [newVec (into [] (y 0))]
          (print newVec))))))
```

Here's the output I'm getting:

```
[T o r o n t o][M o n t r Θ a l][V a n c o u v e r]...
```

How do I go about making it single space so it outputs are `[Toronto][Montreal]...`?

Answer (score 3):

There's a subtle detail: Strings are collections in Clojure (collections of the individual characters), which, mixed with `into` can cause these issues.

`into` takes 2 collections and "pours" the second into the first:

```
user=> (into [1 2 3] (range 4 7))
[1 2 3 4 5 6]

user=> (into [1 2 3] "Hello")
[1 2 3 \H \e \l \l \o]
```

In the second example, all 5 characters of the string `Hello` are "added" as 5 new elements of the vector.

In your case, what you probably want is `conj`:

```
user=> (conj [1 2 3] "Hello")
[1 2 3 "Hello"]
```

...now, since you are creating a new vector with just one element, you can use the vector's syntax directly, with something like `(let [newVec [(y 0)]] ...)`, which means that `newVec` will be  a 1-element vector containing the value returned by `(y 0)`, which is the city name in your case.

**PS**: I see some weird characters in your city names in your example (`Q u Θ b e c` instead of `Q u é b e c`), so you might need to check the encoding of your CSV file (eg. save it as UTF-8 for better results).

Comment: Thanks that works. Also how would I be able to implement a double loop through the newly created vector as I want to locate the pairs of cities that are large and close to each other(i know how to check if theyre close and large just don't know how to implement the for loop in clojure)?

Comment: I'm guessing your CSV file has data about one city per row. Assuming that, you can create one vector or hashmap per row containing the information about a city. Once you have a collection of `cities`, you can use a `for` loop with two variables much like this example: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for#example-542692c7c026201cdc326957

Comment: you want something like `x` in `cities` and `y` in `cities` where they are not the same city, and get sets of `x` and `y` that are both large and close to each other. If you represent the result as sets you can avoid duplicates (eg. "Toronto and Quebec" vs "Quebec and Toronto")

Comment: These comments are really a follow-up question, and should be asked in a new Question. Comments are ephemeral, and should be on topic for the current question.

Comment: Okay this is what I have so far. It does not seem to want to print. I used the original for loop because it returns only the names of the cities whereas if i used the cities function i constructed it will return all columns in the csv file:(defn closest-city-pairs []
 (with-open [rdr (reader)]
  (vec
   (for [line (drop 1 (line-seq rdr))
    :let [y (string/split line #",")]
    :when (= true (large(y 0)))]
    (let [newVec (conj [] (y 0))]
    (for[x newVec
      y newVec
      :when (= true (close x y))]
      (let [newNewVec (conj [] (x y))]
      (println newNewVec)
   )))))))